# Why I can't see Ajax loaded content in code?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've been wondering for quite some time, why when i get ajax response from php and load it with innerHTML into a div, I can visually see content but under source code its nothing?

As an example, this website http://www.hempatia.si/kategorija-pripomocki uses ajax for loading content and I can still see the products in source page.

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Comment: Because "source" shows you the page _source_. Whatever was added via AJAX or JavaScript is not in _source_.

Comment: Install firebug on firefox (or use chrome without installed plugin) then right click on the page and choose inspect element. You'll see the html as it is changed by javaScript.

Comment: Thank you, but I still wonder how does the website I've specified achieves this?

Comment: What is an example of something you do on that website that causes an Ajax load? I clicked a few links at random and they all reloaded the whole page. Please be much more specific about what you did.

Comment: That is not my website but just an example :) When you follow the link I've gave, you can see options for "Next Page" at bottom and order by (few options). If the page onload wasn't loaded with ajax, how is it possible they can order it or go to next page via ajax? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm building similar website and I've considered manipulating JSON response from database via PHP to display articles.

Answer (score 2):

When you use your browser's "View Page Source" (or equivalent) option it shows the original source from when the page first loaded.

To see the "source" reflecting the current state of the page use your browser's dev/debug tools (F12 in Chrome or IE; ctrl-shift-i in FF).

Note that the browser isn't really maintaining the "source" per se, when the page first loads the browser parses the original source to create a DOM for the page and dynamic changes are made to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic content will not come in veiw source. Install firebug for Firefox. You can able to view that content.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your mouse and select inspect element you will see the changes after ajax response